# Log4net with dotnetnuke

Tags: log4net, dotnetnuke

How can i configure Log4net to work in a Dotnetnuke solution?
I am using DNN 5.2
the Global.asax does not have a code behind file to put code to initialize the Log4net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Global.asax.vb (code behind for the global.asax) under App_Code.
For some reason in dotnetnuke the code written inside  in the asax is not called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in the Global.asax file:

```
<script runat="server">
    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Configure log4net here
    End Sub
</script>
```